# させられない: Causative passive or causative + potential?

Tags: passive-voice, causation

そういう作業を彼にさせられないし　そもそもこいつに出来る気がしない

My understand of the sentence is "I cannot let that guy handle that kind of job. To be begin with, I don't feel like he could do it."

させられる read as causative/passive however it makes no sense to me?

Comment: I don't have the confidence to write a proper answer, or even be completely sure of my understanding, but it seems to me that your question contains the answer twice over. You suggest the causative + potential form, then translate it as "cannot let" and say that the causative passive makes no sense. 

Given that, and the fact that passive and potential look the same for ichidan-verbs, and that causative forms are essentially ichidan verbs...

Alternatively, JMdict considers さぜる a separate ichidan verb, making this just the potential form if you prefer to think of it that way.

Answer (score 2):

This させられない is causative potential (+negative), so "**can**not **let** him do it" is a perfectly valid translation.

彼にさせられない might mean "not to be made to do it by him" (causative + passive + negative) depending on the context, but such an interpretation can easily be dismissed from the context.